# Building and Copying Non Web Applications using Build file and Build Definition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am currently working with TFS2012 and VS2012 technology to Build and Deploy Web Application and Non Web Application.

**Research carried out:**
 - Read the Inside the Microsoft Build Engine, Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build book.
 - Read Stackoverflow, msdn, and other forums for help on my problem.

Unfortunately I'm still faced with the issue.

**Current setup:**

I have a:

- Solution called *ClassLib1.sln*
- *Build.proj* file within the solution
- 2 Project within the Solution:

  - *ClassLib1.csproj*  - Non Web Application
  - *MvcApp1.csproj* - Web Application
- Build server that performs the builds
- Build Definition (*DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml*) that builds *Build.proj* file.

The *Build.proj* file contains following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
  <ItemGroup>  
    <DirectoriesToDelete Include="\\server\build\test\MvcApp1" />  
    <DirectoriesToDelete Include="\\server\build\test\ClassLib1" />  
    <SolutionsToBuild Include="ClassLib1.sln" />  
    <ProjectsToPublish Include="MvcApp1\MvcApp1.csproj">  
      <Properties>  
        OutputPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\build\test\ClassLib1\MvcApp1\; 
        UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true;  
        PipelineDependsOnBuild=false;  
        SkipInvalidConfigurations=true;  
        DeployOnBuild=true;  
        DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder;  
        AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;  
        _PackageTempDir=\\server\build\test\MvcApp1  
      </Properties>  
    </ProjectsToPublish>  
    <ProjectsToPublish Include="ClassLib1\ClassLib1.csproj">  
      <Properties>  
        OutputPath=\\server\build\test\ClassLib1\  
      </Properties>  
    </ProjectsToPublish>  
  </ItemGroup>  
  <Target Name="Build">  
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirectoriesToDelete)" />  
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionsToBuild)" />  
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToPublish)" />  
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

**What works:**

When executing the msbuild locally (e.g. *msbuild Build.proj /t:Build*), everything works. Both projects are built and output to the specified *PackageTempDir* or *OutPutPath*.

**Problem at hand:**

However, once I try to perform the build via Build definition then only the *MvcApp1.csproj* files are output in the specified place. The *ClassLib1.csproj* files are missing.

I've tried number of things, nothing worked so far (apart from doing it manually).

Please note I am somewhat new to this, so may have easily miss understood or missed something.

Comment: More information about this case can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b80100f-4d9e-4acc-8975-ea390a0e2ecf/building-and-copying-non-web-applications-using-build-file-and-build-definition

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue after a bit of trial and error.

For the non web app I had modified the ItemGroup to contain:

```
<ProjectsToPublish Include="..\Solution\FolderName\Project\ProjectName.csproj">
  <Properties>OutputPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Environmen\Solution.FolderName.ProjectName;OutDir=C:\CustomBinariesOutDir\Environment\App\</Properties>
</ProjectsToPublish>
```

I've created a Copy Target

```
<Target Name="Copy" AfterTargets="Build">
<CreateItem Include="C:\CustomBinariesOutDir\environment\**\*.*" >
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToCopy"/>
</CreateItem>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="\\serverip\TestBuild\environment\%(FilesToCopy.RecursiveDir)" />
```

It seems the issue was that msbuild didn't allow me directly copy from where the binaries were being built, so I output them into another folder on the same server and then using copy target move them to right place.

Hope this helps others.